# Error disabling the div content

Tags: javascript

The code below should disable a div when it gets clicked, but the problem is after the disable "gets performed" I am still able to select the date from the calendar. Please help me

```
function cycleone() {
    cycleone1(document.getElementById("div1"));
}

function cycleone1(el) {
    try {
        el.disabled = el.disabled ? false : true;
    } catch (E) {}
    if (el.childNodes && el.childNodes.length > 0) {
        for (var x = 0; x < el.childNodes.length; x++) {
            cycleone1(el.childNodes[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post even less code so that we have strictly no idea of what you're up to ? Good thing about not posting any error message though, it might have helped us finding immediately the problem and it's better for creativity if we can only imagine and try to guess....

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable a `<div/>` like this. instead, what you can do is add a invisible curtain on top of it to make it look like it is "disabled"

Here is a Codepen I wrote http://codepen.io/hasin/pen/MwEdEr to demonstrate :)

Comment: hi can you pls show me the above code using text box.

Comment: same, just add textarea inside the div